# Remove RFH2 header from incoming message in MQ

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

Currently i am using Websphere MQ V8.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try{
            MQEnvironment.disableTracing();
            MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "localhost");
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, "1414");
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, "TEST_SVR_CONN");
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "DEVTESTQUEUE");
            //cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_DIRECT_HTTP);
            //cf.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_BINDINGS);
            //set MQServer = 
            //HelloWorldConsumer.HelloWorldProducer();
            MQQueueConnection connection = (MQQueueConnection) cf.createQueueConnection();
            MQSession session = (MQSession) connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MQQueue queue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue("REQUEST");
            //queue.setMessageBodyStyle(WMQConstants.WMQ_MESSAGE_BODY_MQ);
            queue.setTargetClient(WMQConstants.WMQ_TARGET_DEST_MQ);
            queue.setProperty("PROPCTL", "ALL");            
            ((com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue)queue).setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_TARGET_CLIENT, WMQConstants.WMQ_TARGET_DEST_MQ);
            connection.start();
            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
            consumer.setMessageListener(new HelloWorldConsumer()); 
            session.close();                        
            connection.close();         
            System.out.println("------END------");          
         }catch(JMSException je){
            je.printStackTrace();
         }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
```

i have tried by setting TARGCLIENT property to WMQ_TARGET_DEST_MQ and PROPCTL as "NONE/FORCE". Still iam getting the header in the message as
 RFH       ?  ????MQSTR         ?   25504.txt          ?UPLOAD|1||

Comment: Can you tell us what are you trying to do in the above sample? Simply trying to receive message? The setTargetClient is to be used while sending messages, not for receiving. Also the way you are setting property "PROPCTL" on queue is not correct. We can help if you can clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Need to remove the RFH2 header from incoming message and send it to response queue.

Comment: Please see the below code, setTargetClient - send message queue.setMessageBodyStyle(WMQConstants.WMQ_MESSAGE_BODY_MQ); queue.setTargetClient(WMQConstants.WMQ_TARGET_DEST_MQ);
//javax.jms.Destination queue = session.createQueue("REQUEST"); //((com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue)queue).setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_WRITE_ENABLED, true); 
connection.start();
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);  String message1 = fileReader();
Message hellowWorldmessage = session.createTextMessage(message1);
producer.send(msg); Still getting RFH2 header in the message.